# Finding pairs of numbers in substring with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to find max subsequence of specified format like

> [a,b],[c,d] (b>a and c>d)

My algorithm works fine. But when i try to split input string in format **\d{2}** it splits me by one digit. How to fix it! Help, pls!

Here is my main class.

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package pack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author serg_shapoval
 *
 */
public class Pairs {

    public static String pairs(String input) {
        List<Pair> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Pair> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Pair> maxSubqueryList = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] inputArr = input.split("\\d{2}");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputArr));
        for (int i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
            Pair p = new Pair();
            p.setFirstNumber(inputArr[i].charAt(1));
            p.setSecondNumber(inputArr[i].charAt(2));
            list.add(p);
        }
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return "null";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getFirstNumber() < list.get(i).getSecondNumber()
                    && list.get(i + 1).getFirstNumber() > list.get(i + 1).getSecondNumber()) {
                tempList.add(list.get(i));
                tempList.add(list.get(i + 1));
            }

            if (tempList.size() >= maxSubqueryList.size()) {
                maxSubqueryList.clear();
                maxSubqueryList.addAll(tempList);
                tempList.clear();

            }
        }

        return maxSubqueryList.toString();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(pairs("12 34 45 32 12 45 32 4 55 6"));
    }

}
```

And here my Pair class.

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package pack;

/**
 * @author serg_shapoval
 *
 */
public class Pair {

    private int firstNumber;
    private int secondNumber;
    /**
     * @return the firstNumber
     */
    public int getFirstNumber() {
        return firstNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param firstNumber the firstNumber to set
     */
    public void setFirstNumber(int firstNumber) {
        this.firstNumber = firstNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the secondNumber
     */
    public int getSecondNumber() {
        return secondNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param secondNumber the secondNumber to set
     */
    public void setSecondNumber(int secondNumber) {
        this.secondNumber = secondNumber;
    }




}
```

Here is my output using this string "12 34 45 32 12 45 32 4 55 6"

> [,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  4 ,  6]
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
>       at pack.Pairs.pairs(Pairs.java:24)
>       at pack.Pairs.main(Pairs.java:53)

Comment: I'm pretty sure either mfaith's solution or mine is enough to solve your problem. If it is not the case, you should ask for further help or clarifications. Please, consider that the programmers in this community offering their expertise freely; therefore, it is important for you to ensure the follow-up when you ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're wanting to split by 2 digit characters.  That's saying that you want the delimiting string to be a 2 digit sequence.  Let's take a comma delimited string as an example: "foo,abc,def".  The delimiter in this case is a comma.  So when we do .split(",") it yields an array of ["foo", "abc", "def"].  Right?
So in your case, you're putting in a string of "12 34 45 32 12 45 32 4 55 6".  Splitting that on 2-digit number sequences will yield an array of [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " 4 ", " 6"]  because you're saying that 2 numeric characters is what is separating the meaningful data you want.  My guess is that you want the opposite of that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry took me sometime since haven't used java for year. The problem is that the regular expression used by `input.split("\\d{2}");` is the delimiter not what will be returned (I tried it and it returned only spaces).

This could do the trick:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}")
            .matcher("12 34 45 32 12 45 32 4 55 6");
        while (m.find()) {
            allMatches.add(m.group());
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```